# Need a constraint to conditionally avoid certain uniques

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I created and filled the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Assignments(
    ID_CxC CHAR(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    truck_code char(3) NOT NULL REFERENCES Trucks(truck_code),
    driver_code char(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES Drivers(driver_code),
    [date] DATE NOT NULL
);
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(1,1,1,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(2,2,2,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(3,3,3,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(4,4,4,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(5,5,5,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(6,6,6,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(7,1,1,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(8,2,2,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(9,3,3,'06-11-2021');
INSERT Assignments
VALUES(10,4,4,'06-11-2021');
```

I need to create a constraint that will only allow a driver to have more than one truck assigned on a single day if it is the same truck as previously assigned that same day.

I was attempting to write a CHECK constraint where in case UNIQUE(driver_code,date) is broken, the statement would only allow an insert or update if it verifies that UNIQUE(driver_code,truck_code,date) is also false.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your data model and you are missing an entity.  There should be a table where driver/truck/date is unique.  Then another table that can have multiple rows per day.

Comment: I already have the drivers table and the trucks table, where all entries are unique. The table I'm now working on is the one that joins this relation.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your suggestion? Drivers and trucks already have their own table with unique values. The point is that drivers can be assigned more than one truck per day now, as long as it's the same truck as assigned previously.

Answer (score 1):

Write a boolean function that passes in Dateval, Truckval, & Driverval and returns the value of

```
Not Exists (Select id_CxC From Assignments
            Where Date = Dateval and Driver=Driverval
              And Truck<>Truckval)
```

Set up a table check constraint that calls this function, prefaced with the schema name.

Comment: I have tried creating a function returning a BIT datatype with your suggestion, but can't seem to get it working. Could you help further with the function?

Comment: Make your query return a string instead.  Something like Select Case When IsNull(Select  Count(*) From Assignments
            Where Date = Dateval and Driver=Driverval
              And Truck<>Truckval),0)>0 Then 'true' else 'false' End